# Why reflections doesn't want to load my test classes?

Tags: java, class, reflection, classpath

I am using Reflections in Java :

```xml
<dependency>
<groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
<artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
<version>0.9.10</version>
</dependency>
```

I can load every classes except my test classes.

```java
List<ClassLoader> classLoadersList = new LinkedList<ClassLoader>();
classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.contextClassLoader());
classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.staticClassLoader());

Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false /* don't exclude Object.class */), new ResourcesScanner())
    .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoadersList.toArray(new ClassLoader[0]))));
```

And I am using this method :

```java
Set<Class<?>> allClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
```

My test classes are at the same location than the other classes (in src/main/java)

I think that it is on account of the framework.
I think the Reflections don't find the JUnit, so, it can't load the class.
Can I have give a classpath to Reflections ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in target ? => Reflections doesn't see...